# Can't target non-widescreen display with media query

Tags: sass, media-queries

I'm trying to define a media query for non-widescreens, however I can't seem to get the rules right. I've got a square screen, that I'm testing this on.

I tried (min-aspect-ratio:4/3), however that query passes in pretty much any case. (max-aspect-ratio:4/3) doesn't affect my square monitor, so I tried (min-aspect-ratio: 1.25/1 with no results.

I feel like I'm missing something.

```
 @include breakpoint(small) {
        &::before {
            content: '';
            background-image: url('../../images/desi_modal.png');
            background-size: 130%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: bottom right;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -50px;
            right: 45%;
            height: calc(100% + 50px);
            width: 45%;
            z-index: 1;
            @media screen and (max-aspect-ratio:4/3) {
                width: 55%;
                right: 37%;
                background-size: 140%;
            }
            @include breakpoint(xlarge) {
                height: 105%;
                width: 44%;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the css output from that code?

Comment: @anderssonola https://pastebin.com/RriXWQDf